# Transforming the JSON Response using JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to process a nested JSON and flatten it in Apache NiFi, with the help of the JoltTransformation processor by supplying a spec.

Sample JSON:

**Input**

```json
{
  "status": 0,
  "body": {
    "updatetime": 1667946041,
    "timezone": "Europe/Luxembourg",
    "measuregrps": [
      {
        "grpid": 3807008748,
        "attrib": 0,
        "date": 1660928128,
        "created": 1660928165,
        "modified": 1660928167,
        "category": 1,
        "deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
        "hash_deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 62,
            "type": 11,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 16909313,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          },
          {
            "value": 63,
            "type": 135,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          },
          {
            "value": 143,
            "type": 136,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          },
          {
            "value": 396,
            "type": 137,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          },
          {
            "value": 402,
            "type": 138,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          }
        ],
        "comment": null
      },
      {
        "grpid": 3801487301,
        "attrib": 0,
        "date": 1660725664,
        "created": 1660725667,
        "modified": 1660725667,
        "category": 1,
        "deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
        "hash_deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 968,
            "type": 54,
            "unit": -1,
            "algo": 33619969,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          }
        ],
        "comment": null,
        "is_inconclusive": false
      },
      {
        "grpid": 3801485699,
        "attrib": 0,
        "date": 1660725563,
        "created": 1660725596,
        "modified": 1660725597,
        "category": 1,
        "deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
        "hash_deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 72,
            "type": 11,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 16909313,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          },
          {
            "value": 60,
            "type": 135,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          },
          {
            "value": 150,
            "type": 136,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          },
          {
            "value": 366,
            "type": 137,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          },
          {
            "value": 400,
            "type": 138,
            "unit": 0,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 9,
            "appliver": 2421
          }
        ],
        "comment": null
      },
      {
        "grpid": 3799078577,
        "attrib": 2,
        "date": 1660636784,
        "created": 1660636789,
        "modified": 1660636789,
        "category": 1,
        "deviceid": null,
        "hash_deviceid": null,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 61000,
            "type": 1,
            "unit": -3,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255,
            "apppfmid": 7,
            "appliver": 5110101
          }
        ],
        "comment": null
      },
      {
        "grpid": 3781281953,
        "attrib": 2,
        "date": 1659950922,
        "created": 1659950922,
        "modified": 1659950922,
        "category": 1,
        "deviceid": null,
        "hash_deviceid": null,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 6200,
            "type": 1,
            "unit": -2,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255
          }
        ],
        "comment": null
      },
      {
        "grpid": 3781281952,
        "attrib": 2,
        "date": 1659950922,
        "created": 1659950922,
        "modified": 1659950922,
        "category": 1,
        "deviceid": null,
        "hash_deviceid": null,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 1670,
            "type": 4,
            "unit": -3,
            "algo": 0,
            "fm": 255
          }
        ],
        "comment": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Jolt Spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "body": {
        "measuregrps": {
          "*": {
            "measures": {
              "*": {
                "*": "[&1].&"
              }
            },
            "@(3,status)": "[&1].status",
            "@(2,updatetime)": "[&1].updatetime",
            "@(2,timezone)": "[&1].timezone",
            "*": "[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output**

```json
[
  {
    "status": 0,
    "updatetime": 1667905592,
    "timezone": "Europe/Luxembourg",
    "grpid": 3807008748,
    "attrib": 0,
    "date": 1660928128,
    "created": 1660928165,
    "modified": 1660928167,
    "category": 1,
    "deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
    "hash_deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
    "value": [
      62,
      968,
      72,
      61000,
      6200,
      1670
    ],
    "type": [
      11,
      54,
      11,
      1,
      1,
      4
    ],
    "unit": [
      0,
      -1,
      0,
      -3,
      -2,
      -3
    ],
    "algo": [
      16909313,
      33619969,
      16909313,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "fm": [
      255,
      255,
      255,
      255,
      255,
      255
    ],
    "apppfmid": [
      9,
      9,
      9,
      7
    ],
    "appliver": [
      2421,
      2421,
      2421,
      5110101
    ],
    "comment": null
  },
  {
    "value": [
      63,
      60
    ],
    "type": [
      135,
      135
    ],
    "unit": [
      0,
      0
    ],
    "algo": [
      0,
      0
    ],
    "fm": [
      255,
      255
    ],
    "apppfmid": [
      9,
      9
    ],
    "appliver": [
      2421,
      2421
    ],
    "status": 0,
    "updatetime": 1667905592,
    "timezone": "Europe/Luxembourg",
    "grpid": 3801487301,
    "attrib": 0,
    "date": 1660725664,
    "created": 1660725667,
    "modified": 1660725667,
    "category": 1,
    "deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
    "hash_deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
    "comment": null,
    "is_inconclusive": false
  },
  {
    "status": 0,
    "updatetime": 1667905592,
    "timezone": "Europe/Luxembourg",
    "grpid": 3801485699,
    "attrib": 0,
    "date": 1660725563,
    "created": 1660725596,
    "modified": 1660725597,
    "category": 1,
    "deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
    "hash_deviceid": "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
    "comment": null
  },
  {
    "status": 0,
    "updatetime": 1667905592,
    "timezone": "Europe/Luxembourg",
    "grpid": 3799078577,
    "attrib": 2,
    "date": 1660636784,
    "created": 1660636789,
    "modified": 1660636789,
    "category": 1,
    "deviceid": null,
    "hash_deviceid": null,
    "comment": null
  },
  {
    "status": 0,
    "updatetime": 1667905592,
    "timezone": "Europe/Luxembourg",
    "grpid": 3781281953,
    "attrib": 2,
    "date": 1659950922,
    "created": 1659950922,
    "modified": 1659950922,
    "category": 1,
    "deviceid": null,
    "hash_deviceid": null,
    "comment": null
  },
  {
    "status": 0,
    "updatetime": 1667905592,
    "timezone": "Europe/Luxembourg",
    "grpid": 3781281952,
    "attrib": 2,
    "date": 1659950922,
    "created": 1659950922,
    "modified": 1659950922,
    "category": 1,
    "deviceid": null,
    "hash_deviceid": null,
    "comment": null
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```json
[ {
  "status" : 0,
  "updatetime" : 1667905592,
  "timezone" : "Europe/Luxembourg",
  "grpid" : 3807008748,
  "attrib" : 0,
  "date" : 1660928128,
  "created" : 1660928165,
  "modified" : 1660928167,
  "category" : 1,
  "deviceid" : "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
  "hash_deviceid" : "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
  "value" : 62,
  "type" : 11,
  "unit" : 0,
  "algo" : 16909313,
  "fm" : 255,
  "apppfmid" : 9,
  "appliver" : 2421,
  "comment" : null
}, {
  "status" : 0,
  "updatetime" : 1667905592,
  "timezone" : "Europe/Luxembourg",
  "grpid" : 3807008748,
  "attrib" : 0,
  "date" : 1660928128,
  "created" : 1660928165,
  "modified" : 1660928167,
  "category" : 1,
  "deviceid" : "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
  "hash_deviceid" : "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
  "value" : 968,
  "type" : 54,
  "unit" : -1,
  "algo" : 33619969,
  "fm" : 255,
  "apppfmid" : 9,
  "appliver" : 2421,
  "comment" : null
},
{
  "value" : 63,
  "type" : 135,
  "unit" : 0,
  "algo" : 0,
  "fm" : 255,
  "apppfmid" : 9,
  "appliver" : 2421,
  "status" : 0,
  "updatetime" : 1667905592,
  "timezone" : "Europe/Luxembourg",
  "grpid" : 3801487301,
  "attrib" : 0,
  "date" : 1660725664,
  "created" : 1660725667,
  "modified" : 1660725667,
  "category" : 1,
  "deviceid" : "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
  "hash_deviceid" : "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
  "comment" : null,
  "is_inconclusive" : false
},
{
  "value" : 60,
  "type" : 135,
  "unit" : 0,
  "algo" : 0,
  "fm" : 255,
  "apppfmid" : 9,
  "appliver" : 2421,
  "status" : 0,
  "updatetime" : 1667905592,
  "timezone" : "Europe/Luxembourg",
  "grpid" : 3801487301,
  "attrib" : 0,
  "date" : 1660725664,
  "created" : 1660725667,
  "modified" : 1660725667,
  "category" : 1,
  "deviceid" : "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
  "hash_deviceid" : "01fc9191c2e72ba05397211f47ec0d0e3db71ac3",
  "comment" : null,
  "is_inconclusive" : false
}
]
```

So my expectation is to have flatten the JSON and have single values for each object, after which I plan to send this over to the ConvertJsontoSql processor within the NiFi to have the records inserted into PostgresDB.

https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

Also, what does `is_inconclusive` mean I can see it gets added to my output when using Jolt Transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the values by `grpid` along with indexes of `measures` array(while looping within this array's elements) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "body": {
        "measuregrps": {
          "*": {
            "measures": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "@(6,status)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].status", // @(6,status) -> going the tree 6 levels up (to traverse "{" 6 times ) in order to reach the level of the attribute "status", "@(4,grpid) -> to traverse ":"(element on th right hand side) once, and "{" three times(total four level), [&2] -> to reach the level of indexes of "measures" array and produce results in array manner by using "[]" notation
                  "@(5,updatetime)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].updatetime",
                  "@(5,timezone)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].timezone",
                  "@(3,grpid)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].grpid",
                  "@(3,date)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].date",
                  "@(3,created)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].created",
                  "@(3,modified)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].modified",
                  "@(3,category)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].category",
                  "@(3,deviceid)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].deviceid",
                  "@(3,hash_deviceid)": "@(4,grpid)[&2].hash_deviceid",
                  "@": "@(4,grpid)[&2].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // pick only single value from the repeating components of the array values
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which will yield a flattened result as needed.

P.S : *I don't know and didn't encounter `is_inconclusive` within the Jolt context.*

Comment: Thank you, I tried the `MANY` option of the cardinality but want each value to be a flattened. I have updated the expected output to be more precise. As I am unable to paste long text here. I want all the records from the response to be as key value pair, as the NiFi tool checks for the Key as the tables column names.

Comment: Thank you so much it works a charm, could you add please help me with adding some insights within the jolt spec so that it would help me understand what each steps are doing.